# is std::declval<bool&>() = std::declval<std::nullptr_t>() well-formed?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, libstdc++, well-formed

[here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/testsuite/20_util/is_assignable/value.cc#L176) is a libstdcxx static_assert:

```
static_assert(!std::is_assignable<bool&, std::nullptr_t>::value, "Error");
```

From [cppreference: is_assignable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_assignable):

> **If the expression `std::declval<T>() = std::declval<U>()` is well-formed** in unevaluated context, provides the member constant value equal true. Otherwise, value is false. Access checks are performed as if from a context unrelated to either type.

so, libstdcxx think it is not assignable, of course, [gcc cannot pass this case](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tvM5JyTduMdYj9Jd)

In opposite, [clang can pass this case](https://wandbox.org/permlink/b9Ur1bCxeECORKrm)

is `std::declval<bool&>() = std::declval<std::nullptr_t>()` well-formed, iow, clang or gcc, who objects to the standard here?

Comment: I would be curious to see what the compilers think of "`void foo(bool &bar) { bar=nullptr; }`". gcc 8 doesn't like it, and issues a diagnostic pointing towards direct initialization, and doesn't have a problem with `(bool)nullptr`.

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.8 _Otherwise, if the initialization is direct-initialization, the source type is std::nullptr_­t, and the destination type is bool, the initial value of the object being initialized is false._                                                   
               it seems the standard doesn't clarify `bool&` and `nullptr`.

Comment: Your question is about assignment, not initialization, so it doesn't need to clarify for `bool&`. To perform the assignment there would have to be an implicit conversion from `nullptr` to `bool`, and no such implicit conversion exists. Only conversions performed explicitly using direct-initialization are allowed, e.g.`b = bool(nullptr);` or `b = (bool)nullptr;`